How to apply different kinds of error regions to some subplots of a facet grid
I have a Seaborn facet grid with multiple 4 rows and 2 cols. I want to map lineplots onto the grid from a melted dataframe (with 4 variables and 2 cats) and apply error bars to the top three rows but not the last (it is based on boolean data and error bars are not appropriate).
Using an example dataset:
import seaborn as sns

fmri = sns.load_dataset('fmri')
gg = sns.FacetGrid(data=fmri, col="region", row="event")
gg.map(sns.lineplot, "timepoint", "signal", errorbar="sd")


Is there any way to remove (or not plot in the first place) the errors bars on the bottom row?

Removing the error region
You could remove the error regions afterward by looping through the axes:
import seaborn as sns

fmri = sns.load_dataset('fmri')
gg = sns.FacetGrid(data=fmri, col="region", row="event")
gg.map(sns.lineplot, "timepoint", "signal", errorbar="sd")

for (row, col), ax in gg.axes_dict.items():
    if row == 'cue':
        ax.collections[0].remove()


Custom plot function
Alternatively, you could map a custom function to the facet grid. Inside that custom function, a test can check whether the provided y-values for that subplot are similar to booleans. As seaborn converts all values to a same type (floats), testing the number of unique y values would be a way to determine that all the values are similar to booleans.
The custom function gets 3 parameters:

a pandas series (column of the dataframe, reduced to the subplot) for the x values
similar for the corresponding y values
a color

import seaborn as sns

def custom_lineplot(x, y, color):
    errorbar = 'sd' if len(y.unique() > 2) else None
    sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y, color=color, errorbar=errorbar)

fmri = sns.load_dataset('fmri')
gg = sns.FacetGrid(data=fmri, col="region", row="event")
gg.map(custom_lineplot, "timepoint", "signal")


thank you this, works well and very much appreciated.

Did you prefer the first or the second approach?  The custom function would be more robust when you make changes to the plot (e.g. plotting new rows or adding information).

I'm just working on a single graph for a publication at the moment so the first approach was adequate. I will use the second approach for any future applications like this though! thanks again
